# svg file not displaying on img control

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, svg

I am trying to show `SVG` file on `img` control in `angular10` but it's not showing up. If I change file to `jpg` its working for the same control. I have `img` control inside `nav` bar.

This is my code along with `css`

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
  <a style="padding-top: 0px;" class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img  class="img-responsive" width="90px" height="35px"  src="/assets/Plogo.svg"> </a>
  <button
    class="navbar-toggler"
    type="button"
    aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div  class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
  </div>
</nav>

.nav-link:hover {
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

.nav-link-collapse:after {
  float: right;
  content: '\f067';
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}

.nav-link-show:after {
  float: right;
  content: '\f068';
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}

.nav-item ul.nav-second-level {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.nav-item ul.nav-second-level > .nav-item {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.navbar-expand-lg .sidenav {
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

How `Plogo.svg` file looks like

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="900" height="439" viewBox="0 0 900 439">
  <image width="900" height="439" xlink:href="data:img/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA4QAAAG3CAYAAADsP5sRAAAJwElEQVR4nO3XQQEAIACEsNP5ErkJggg=="/>
</svg>
```

Comment: What's the markup of Plogo.svg?

Comment: @RobertLongson - my `svg` file has so much text. I just added the reduced sample of it. Please check updated question.

Comment: Try it with another SVG file and see if it's work.

Comment: @MoustafaZaki - I tried with different svg, it working.

Comment: @DearComrade So the issue in plogo.svg file make sure the file is a valid svg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My `svg` file was not correct. I used another `svg` and it worked.